# Javascript and jQuery: onclick event listener to increment index in while loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, onclick

I have a code which displays a circle and an ellipse  when I press "S" (the positions are chosen among 18 possible combinations). Then I have a while loop: I would like that, at every iteration, if the circle is touched a new position is generated right away and, if the circle is NOT touched for 3 consecutive times, a new position is generated.

I have 2 problems: 1) It seems that I cannot put the increment (positions ++) in the if/else statement only. 2) The second iteration  does not update the positions of circle and ellipse (I should use a jQuery $ attribute?)

How can I solve this?

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="cssFiles/blackBackground.css">

  <script src="jsFiles/drawEllipse.js"></script> 
  <script src="jsFiles/drawCircle.js"></script> 
  <script src="jsFiles/newPosition.js"></script> 
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src='https://code.responsivevoice.org/responsivevoice.js'></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>



  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="1260" height="1000" style="border:1px solid red;"></canvas>
  <p id="1"></p>
  <p id="2"></p>

    <script>
    var ellipse = [[-150,-300],[-150,0],[-150,300],[150,-300],[150,0],[150,300]];
    var circle = [[-350,-300],[-350,0],[-350,300],[350,-300],[350,0],[350,300]];
    var radius = 95;
    var positions = 0; 
    var clicks  = 0;   
    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    $(document).ready(function() {
        document.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {


        if  (e.keyCode === 83) { // "Start" is pressed
                while (positions<6){  
             // generate first position      
                var idx = newPosition(ellipse,circle,radius)
                var idx_ellipse = idx[0];
                var idx_circle = idx[1];
                var xRight = circle[idx_circle][0] + radius + canvas.width/2 ;
                var xLeft = circle[idx_circle][0] - radius+ canvas.width/2;
                var yTop = circle[idx_circle][1] - radius + canvas.height/2;
                var yBottom = circle[idx_circle][1] + radius + canvas.height/2;


                document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                  clicks++;

                 if (e.clientX< xRight && e.clientX> xLeft && e.clientY< yBottom && e.clientY> yTop) { //circle is correctly touched
                      var idx = newPosition(ellipse,circle,radius) // new position generated
                      positions++

                  }
                  else if (clicks > 3) {
                    var idx = newPosition(ellipse,circle,radius) // new position generated
                    positions++
                  }

             }, false); //end of touch listener 

               } // end of while loop 
            } // end of "Start" keycode listener  
        }); //end of keydown listener

      }) //end of document function

 function newPosition(ellipse,circle,radius){
                 var idx_ellipse = Math.floor( Math.random() *6);
                drawEllipse(ellipse[idx_ellipse][0],ellipse[idx_ellipse][1],radius,2.5,1);
                // Check position of ellipse and draw circle on the other side
                if (ellipse[idx_ellipse][0] == -150){
                  var idx_circle = Math.floor(Math.random() * (5 - 3 +1)) + 3;
                  drawCircle(circle[idx_circle][0],circle[idx_circle][1],radius,2.5,1);
                }
                else if(ellipse[idx_ellipse][0] == 150) {
                  var idx_circle = Math.floor(Math.random() * (2 - 0 +1)) + 0;
                  drawCircle(circle[idx_circle][0],circle[idx_circle][1],radius,2.5,1);
                }  

                   return [idx_ellipse,idx_circle];
                } 
    </script>


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: remove the space from `position ++`

Comment: `clicks ++` there is space between clicks and ++, increment operation syntax is not correct

Comment: ops that was a mistake in adding it last minute. But doesn't solve my problem, any idea what i should change to have my code working as I want to?

Comment: Wow you are adding an event listener in a while loop itself triggered by an user event ? Glad to meet you. But stop. I'm not sure what you though it will do, but clearly you don't want to do that.

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar it could have worked if there was a leading `+` (`+clicks ++`) even though I would only consider this as an "*this code is meant to be unreadable*".

Comment: @Kaiido, it should not be this crazy. My problem is that if I press S to generate a new position then the positions are correctly changed and retained but the increments to keep track of the consecutive "wrong" clicks is wrong for some reason. If, instead, I generate a new position inside the onclick() event listener, then the opposite happens: increments are correct but position of the circle and ellips is not retained

Comment: search for "function scope" on google. Also, when you call twice addEventListener('click', func) at **each** click, func will be called twice. So in your case it is called six times * the number time you pressed "s".